# ValueError: A target array with shape (160, 299, 299, 3) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning. I am trying to use depthwise separable convolutions on cancer skin dataset X contains 200 images with shape (299,299,3) and Y"mask" contains 200 images with same shape as X. and it is binary classification.

here is the error:

"ValueError: A target array with shape (160, 299, 299, 3) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output."

I dont know where have I gone wrong. Help needed in resolving the error.

```
def first(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=1):
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=filters,
                        kernel_size=kernel_size,
                        strides=strides,
                        padding='same',
                        use_bias=False)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = ReLU()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=4, strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    return x

def sep_bn(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=1):
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=filters,
                        kernel_size=kernel_size,
                        strides=strides,
                        padding='same',
                        use_bias=False)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return x

def block(tensor,filters):
    
    x = sep_bn(tensor, filters=filters, kernel_size=3)
    x = ELU()(x)
    x = sep_bn(x, filters=filters, kernel_size=3)
    x = ELU()(x)
    x = sep_bn(x, filters=filters, kernel_size=3)

    tensor = Add()([tensor, x])
    return tensor

input = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))

my_model = first(input, 16, 3, strides=2)
my_model = block(my_model,16)

my_model = first(my_model, 32, 3, strides=2)
my_model = block(my_model,32)

my_model = first(my_model, 48, 3, strides=2)
my_model = block(my_model,48)

my_model = first(my_model, 64, 3, strides=2)
my_model = block(my_model,64)

my_model = first(my_model, 96, 3, strides=2)
my_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(my_model)

my_model = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(my_model)
output = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(my_model)
Xception_model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
print(Xception_model.summary())
```

```
Xception_model.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss= ['binary_crossentropy'], metrics=['accuracy'])

history = Xception_model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test, y_test) ,epochs=150, batch_size=32 ,verbose=1
```

Comment: Please run:

print(y_train.shape)
print(y_train)

What do you see?

Comment: @AndreasKaufmann here are the shapes print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape) (160, 299, 299, 3)
(160, 299, 299, 3)
(40, 299, 299, 3)
(40, 299, 299, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model output is "Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')" layer, it produces a number between 0 and 1.

However, your 'y_train.shape' is '(160, 299, 299, 3)', which is a 299x299x3 tensor for each input item. For 'binary_crossentropy' you should provide 0 or 1 values as y_train. I.e. the expected 'y_train.shape' is '(160, )' and 'y_train.shape' should be an array with 0s and 1s (ground truth labels). In your case it looks like y_train is an image (just as an input).